# How to do null checks in Scala in an idiomatic way?

Tags: scala

```
case class Account(
                          val name: String,
                          val uuid: String,
                          val lat: Double,
                          val lng: Double
                        )
}

object Account {
  def create(row: Row): Option[YellowAccount] = {
    val name = row.getAs[String]("store_name")
    val uuid = row.getAs[String]("uuid")
    val latO = row.getAs[String]("latitude")
    val lngO = row.getAs[String]("longitude")

    // How do you do null checks here in an idiomatic way?
    if (latO == null || lngO == null) {
      return None
    }

    Some(YellowAccount(name, uuid, latO.toDouble, lngO.toDouble))
  }

}
```

lat/long are compulsory fields in `Account`. How do you do null checks in an idiomatic way?

Comment: Hint: `Option(null) == None`. `for { latO <- Option(row.getAs[String]("latitude")); lngO <- Option(...) } yield YellowAccount(name, uuid, latO.toDouble, lngO.toDouble)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Option`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Option) type to handle `null` values. You just wrap a nullable value in `Option` and then you can pattern match on it or something else. In your example, I think the most concise way to combine 4 nullable values is for-comprehension:

```
import scala.util.Try

object Account {
  def create(row: Row): Option[YellowAccount] = {
    for {
      name <- Option( row.getAs[String]("store_name") )
      uuid <- Option( row.getAs[String]("uuid") )
      latO <-    Try( row.getAs[String]("latitude").toDouble ).toOption
      lngO <-    Try( row.getAs[String]("longitude").toDouble ).toOption
    } yield 
      YellowAccount(name, uuid, latO, lngO)  
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Another thing here is `_.toDouble` conversion, which may throw an exception if it fails to parse the string, so you can wrap it in [`Try`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.Try) instead (I updated the code above).

**EDIT2**

To clarify what's happening here:

- when you wrap a value in [`Option`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Option) it becomes `None` if the value is `null`, or `Some(...)` with the value otherwise
- similarly when wrapping something that may throw an exception in [`Try`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.Try), it becomes either `Failure` with the exception, or `Success` with the value
- [`toOption`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.Try@toOption:Option[T]) method converts `Try` to `Option` in a straightforward way: `Failure` becomes `None`, `Success` becomes `Some`
- in the for-comprehension if *any* of the four `Option`s returns `None` (i.e. one of them was `null` of failed to parse a number), the whole statement returns `None`, and only if *each* of the four yields a value, they are passed to the `YellowAccount` constructor

Comment: What does the Try do? Does it just not yield? And What does option wrap do? Does it also not yield?

Comment: for comprehension won't work, you can't mix `Option` and `Try` like that.

Comment: @Dima thanks, my bad that I didn't check the code after the edit. It's easy to fix though, I can just call `.toOption` on `Try`

Comment: Why do you need to put first two values into `for` comprehension? Doesn't  make sense to me. Also, presumably, exceptions are slow, it's easier to check for `null` this way or another.

Comment: @VictorMoroz because from the original code I derived that `getAs` method may return `null`. Regarding exceptions, it's not about `null`, but about parsing `String` to `Double`: `toDouble` may throw, so you should handle it one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer suggests, you can use `Option` to handle possible nulls. You can't use `for` comprehension the way it is suggested there, but there are several ways around it. The easiest, probably is to `.zip` the two Options together, and then map over the result:

```
  Option(row.getAs[latitude])
    .zip(Option(row.getAs[String]("longitude")))
    .map { case (lat, long) => 
      YellowAccount(
        row.getAs[String]("store_name"), 
        row.getAs[String]("uuid"), 
        lat.toDouble, 
        long.toDouble
       )
     }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use toDiuble inside of an Option, if the value is null, you'll get a NullPointerException. Also in your answer you don't mix Option and Try, so you *could* use for (also see my update). Anyway, an alternative approach is good, I'm not fond of for-comprehension in general, but in this case it's just more concise..

Comment: @laughedelic you are right about `toDouble`.  Fixed that.
I am not sure about the "more concise" part ... I think, it's not ;) In general, I am not a big fan of creating variables that are used exactly once without a reason. But that's a question of taste.

Comment: Why do you think `zip`/`map` is better than straight `for` comprehension?